# Finding recurring patterns in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

Ok the problem is that given a fraction `eg:1/3` the answer `0.3333333` should represented as `0.(3)`
and `0.2325555` as `0.232(5)` i have figured out a way to split the string when its a single digit repeating:

using `re.findall(r'^(.+?)((.)\3+)$', '42344444' )[0][:-1]` (ignoring the `0.` before the number)

but i want to know how to do this if the pattern is `0.324324324..` to get `0.(324)`

Comment: Are you given the numbers as a fraction or a floating point? If it's the later, this is impossible.

Comment: Is the aim to discover recurring patterns of arbitrary length?  If so, that cannot be done with regex.

Comment: actually forget about the fraction part .. say you are give the string `23154545454` how would you split the string into the non recurring part and the recurring part

Comment: ok to make things simpler lets assume strings are of length 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `+` after `.` in the recurring part:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^(.+?)((.+)\3+)$', '42344343434' )[0][:-1]
('42344', '343434')
```